# I tried to separate alloc and initWithRed... messages, but it doesn't seems to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicolor

Sorry if it is asked somewhere, but as a beginner, I need a very specific answer for my question. Where is wrong, correction and suggestions.

I write those under application didFinishLaunchingWithOption:

```
UIColor *myBackgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:.87 green:.77 blue:.56 alpha:.99];
[window setBackgroundColor:myBackgroundColor];
```

It worked, and change the color of the background, and then I try to separate those two messages.

```
UIColor *myBackgroundColor = [UIColor alloc];
[myBackgroundColor initWithRed:.87 green:.77 blue:.56 alpha:.99]
[window setBackgroundColor:myBackgroundColor];
```

How should I code to make it run correctly? I will need both reason and corrections. Thanks a lot.

Comment: More question. if I need to write "myBackgroundColor = [myBackgroundColor initWithRed:.87 green:.77 blue:.56 alpha:.99]" why would "[myUIView initWithFrame:myCGRect];" work well?

Comment: If you have another question you should ask it as a new question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assume that `alloc` and `init` has the same return value.

The following should work:

```
UIColor *myBackgroundColor = [UIColor alloc];
myBackgroundColor = [myBackgroundColor initWithRed:.87 green:.77 blue:.56 alpha:.99]
[window setBackgroundColor:myBackgroundColor];
```

I don't understand why you'd want to add the extra line though.

Comment: @Shane Hsu, I see that you're new, so I just want to inform you that you're supposed to accept the answer that helped you the most. You do so by clicking the green check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use...

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.87 green:0.77 blue:0.56 alpha:0.99];
```

Comment: Solid advice, but not an answer to the question.