# Return value handling of init message

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, initialization, uicolor

I understand that the return value of UIColor initWithRed needs to be handled,
(see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294746/i-tried-to-separate-alloc-and-initwithred-messages-but-it-doesnt-seems-to-wo) for reference.)

Now my question is, why would

```
UIView *myUIView = [UIView alloc];
[myUIView initWithFrame:myCGRect];
```

worked successfully. I didn't handle the return value that initWithFrame returns!

Or did I just get it all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alloc` and `init` has the same return value in this case. The `init` method just modifies the object created by `alloc`, so it returns the same object as `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

This will *almost always* not be a problem. (For `UIView` it won't be)

It is acceptable for an object to return something different from init, however, so as a practice you should use the value returned from that.

```
UIView *myUIView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myCGRect];
```